# Regex: exclude trailing .0 but include all strings

Tags: regex

I have a number of floats/strings that look as follows:
12339.0
133339
159.0
dfkkei
something
32439

Some of them have trailing .0. How can I show all the numbers without the trailing .0 as a regular repression, including the items that are not a number? I tried something like that, hoping it would exclude all .0 from the capture group, but it doesn't work: `(.*)(:?.0)?`

https://regex101.com/r/sC6jO2/1

Comment: So, is it for Python? Use `r'\.0+$'` there to remove those values

Comment: Or, without using regex do a string replace of `'.0 '` with `' '` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a simpler regex:

```
\.0+$
```

And replace with an empty string, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2yG1/1).

The regex matches a `.` (`\.`) followed with 1 or more zeros (`0+`) up to the end of string (`$`).

If you plan to *match* two groups as in your initial attempt, use

```
^(.*?)(?:\.0+)?$
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2yG1/2)

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)`  - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible (=*lazily*), up to a
- `(?:\.0+)?` - optional sequence of `.` + one or more zeros
- `$` - at the end of the string.

Comment: It is values in a pandas dataframe to be exact. That's why I was looking for the opposite so I could do a df['column'].str.extract(regex, expand=True)

Comment: Use `^(.*?)(?:\.0+)?$`